# how to loop through different variables in python

Tags: python, function, loops, variable-assignment

I have a series of variables named `model1`, `model2`, ...

I want to loop through each of them and perform some tasks. I was wondering how can I in each iteration assign `modelx` to the same placeholder variable `model` and work on `model`? I thought about working out a function that applies to `model` but it'd be much less convenient... Am I missing anything? Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks very much!

Comment: This is really vague.  Can you provide an example in pseudocode, or provide real code that doesn't work and ask us to fix it?

Comment: `models = [model1, model2, model3]` then `for model in models: dostuff()` ?

Comment: @RafaelC ah yes silly me thanks a lot! --- wait, no it does not work...

Comment: @shenglih which part of "creating a list" and "iterating over it" never works?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is the crappiest way to do it ever, but this is what first popped into my head:

```
n = 1
models = []
while n <= 5: #or whatever number your modelx thing goes up to
    models.append(eval('model'+str(n)))
    n+=1

for model in models:
    #do your thing
```

In other words, it basically iterates through all the different numbers of model you have and uses `eval` to turn that into the actual variable. It then appends this to a master list, which you can then do with what you will.

Disclaimer: `eval()` should be used sparingly and this might not be a great use, especially if this is somehow connected with user input. There are probably better solutions anyway. Your naming model also isn't the greatest. Maybe you could've put them all in a list to begin with:

```
models = [model1, model2, model3, ... , modelx]
for model in models:
    #do stuff
```